# How can I change brightness through terminal

Tags: 11.04, brightness

Now I can change it by `Fn`+ `arrow right` but now I need  to do it via my shell script

Answer (score 30, accepted):

adding to what [Michał Šrajer](https://askubuntu.com/users/22908/michal-srajer) says in some cases the brightness may be controlled from `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` as is the case with my dell vostro 3400 and  my the brightness range is 0-15. You may have to look for other folder in `/sys/class` if the same path as mine doesnot exit.

Comment: it works (0-9 for me)

Comment: See my comment on Michał Šrajer's post below for a way to alias this for easy use.

Comment: How to change it? is not by `sudo nano /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` ...

Comment: for me it was via `sudo vim /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Comment: Also, don't forget that instead of `vim`ing or `nano`ing to edit the file, you can simply `echo  15 >  /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Comment: In my case it's `$ cat /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight/max_brightness` and `max_brightness` is 800.

Answer (score 21):

In your script you can send the equivalent keystrokes that correspond to Fn+Right Arrow and Fn+Left Arrow i.e. Brightness Up and Down respectively

Install `xdotool` from the Software Center

Then in your script to increase brightness:

```
xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp
```

To decrease Brightness

```
xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown
```

Comment: +1, the only non requiring admin privileges

Comment: So I was able to do this in the terminal in Ubuntu 15.04 with both the MATE and Unity desktops. However, when I bind this to any key combination it does not work.

Comment: This still works for XFCE on 15.04.

Comment: This still works (for me, at least) for XFCE on 18.04. Yet it doesn't allow to set to a fixed value, only steps up or down.

Comment: I run `lxqt` on lubuntu 20_04, what should I write for `key`? `xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown` does not work.

Answer (score 14):

You could install xbacklight package `$sudo apt-get install xbacklight` and then if you want to increase the brightness level, type `$xbacklight -inc <level in a range of 10 - 100>` and vice versa: `$xbacklight -dec <level in a range of 10 - 100>`.

Read `xbacklight --help` to see more options.

Comment: my notebook keyboard is broken, the external usb one has no key for that.  the -dec option works, the -inc dont! but the -set does! so I will just create a simple script, thx!!!

Comment: Lubuntu 20_04 outputs `No outputs have backlight property`.

Answer (score 9):

call:

```
sudo su -c 'echo 30 > /proc/acpi/video/VID/LCD0/brightness'
```

The path may be different in your system. To list all available call:

```
find /proc/acpi/video -name 'brightness'
```

To see possible values for each, just cat the file:

```
cat /proc/acpi/video/VID/LCD0/brightnes
```

Comment: have not  /proc/acpi/video/ at all. find /proc/acpi -name 'brightness'  prints nothing

Comment: I think the command is `sudo sh -c` rather than `sudo su -c`

Comment: @sagarchalise: it is more or less the same, `su` launch a `sh`

Comment: `sudo su -c 'echo 4 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness'` worked for me. Using a Samsung laptop and oddly enough the range is 0-7.

Comment: I tried to write a function to call this very easily - wound up with `function bri { sudo su -c 'echo $1 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness';}` - but it didn't work for me. So as a substitute, I created aliases `bri0` through `bri7` which worked -- see [here](http://pastebin.com/ZX21bEvm).

Comment: function brightness {
    sudo su -c "echo $1 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"
} did the trick for me.

Comment: Mine was under `/sys/devices/pci0000.../drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness`. `cd /sys; find -iname 'bright*'` is how I found it.

Answer (score 3):

Install xbacklight it is very light and useful.

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

Then use xbacklight -set 60 where number can varry from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu's default desktop environment, Unity, has set of `dbus` methods that allow setting/getting brightness without need for `sudo` access.

Note well, that for this to work, one will need to have `DISPLAY=:0` variable declared in the script.

Personally, I use `qdbus` application , with all the appropriate interface and method names combined into a nice function and store it in `.bashrc`

```
unityBrightness()
{ # change brightness in Unity/ Gnome
qdbus org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power\
      /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power\
       org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.SetPercentage "$1"

}
```

Usage of this function would be like :

```
unityBrightness 50
```

, where `50` is the percentage.

Equivalent  `dbus-send` command would be

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply\
    --dest=org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power\
    /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power \
    org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.SetPercentage uint32:"$1"
```

Comment: Getting `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method “SetPercentage”` :(

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using laptop.**

You can use this command: `sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=xx`

Which `xx` is the brightness in hex ranging from 0 (brightest) to FF (no brightness at all). I Use `E0` when working on battery.

Comment: Do not work, here

Comment: @enzotib : It works fine with me using 11.04. And I think it is only for a laptop.

Comment: Not working in DELL inspiron

Comment: Works on my Acer Aspire One

Comment: This is the only one that works for me on a Gateway / Packard Bell.

Comment: @Binarylife who do I undo this? Because I don't understand the command. I didn't think it changed my brightness. But the command ran without throwing an error. So, I wanted to undo this for future issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little utility to set brightness from terminal: [linux-brightness-binary](https://github.com/Stichoza/linux-brightness-binary)

Then you can set brightness like this: `sudo bright 5` or `sudo bright 0`

**0-15** works for me on Asus UX50V Laptop running Debian 7

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu trusty 14.04, this command works fine

`sudo su -c 'echo 12 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness'`

You can change the value 12 to any value from `0 to 20`

Thanks @Michał Šrajer and @sagarchalise