# Brightness Problem Ubuntu 15.10 (Dell inspiron 5737)

Tags: brightness, backlight

i need help how to fix my laptop **Dell Inspiron 5737** brightness being stuck at max, when i press keys on my laptop scale shows that it "works" but brightness remain the same at max and it is killing me

i have tryed few solutions including this one but without any success

> sudo nano /etc/default/grub
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
>
> sudo update-grub

can someone please tell me some solution that might work, btw since i am new to ubuntu so please be specific to what i need to do and where as i am still learning

thanks in advance.

Comment: This [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/401311/205638) is for a different model, but still might work. If not, edit your post and include the output of `ls /sys/class/backlight/`

Comment: Can you please try out the qdbus command listed here http://askubuntu.com/a/739188/295286.  Considering that brightness through keys should go to dbus anyway, I'm suspecting it won't work, but perhaps.